# Concurrent program parameter of date type gave error ORA-01843: not a valid month

Tags: sql, oracle, xml-publisher

I have 2 parameters in my report Query of datatype date, I have selected the `fnd_standard_date` as value set, here is my query

```
Select ordered_date, order_number, customer_id
From order_tbl xx       
Where  NVL(:P_ORDER_NUMBER, xx.order_number) = xx.order_number
 and xx.ordered_date between NVL(trunc(TO_DATE(:P_FROM_DATE, 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS')), xx.ORDERED_DATE) and NVL(trunc(TO_DATE(:P_TO_DATE, 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS'), xx.ORDERED_DATE)
    AND NVL(:P_CUSTOMER, xx.customer_id) = xx.customer_id>
```

In SQLDeveloper the result is ok, but in Oracle apps, I am facing

> java.sql.SQLDataException: ORA-01843: not a valid month

What value set can I use for this parameter?
And what format can I pass?

Comment: what formats are your dates in?

Comment: in default format 'DD-MON-YYYY', but also tried 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS'

Comment: If P_DATE is already datatype DATE, why are you calling TO_DATE for it? That will do an implicit TO_CHAR using your session's NLS_DATE_FORMAT, and would explain the differing behaviour. Or is P_DATE really a string?

Comment: Have you tried `TO_DATE(:P_FROM_DATE, 'DD-MON-YYYY')`?

Answer (score 1):

If your parameters are already DATEs as you say, then you should not be calling `TO_DATE()` for them. That will do an implicit conversion of the date to a string using the session's NLS_DATE_FORMAT, and then try to convert that string back into a date using the format model you have specified.

That will work if NLS_DATE_FORMAT happens to match what you specified, but you should not rely on that being the case, and should not do implicit conversions; and you're doing more work than you need to anyway.

So just simplify it to:

```
Select ordered_date, order_number, customer_id
From order_tbl xx       
Where  NVL(:P_ORDER_NUMBER, xx.order_number) = xx.order_number
and xx.ordered_date between NVL(trunc(:P_FROM_DATE), xx.ORDERED_DATE)
   and NVL(trunc(:P_TO_DATE), xx.ORDERED_DATE)
AND NVL(:P_CUSTOMER, xx.customer_id) = xx.customer_id>
```

If you're running it from SQL Developer with P_DATE_FROM and _TO declared as strings via the `variable` command, then you will need to use `TO_DATE()` of course. The two situations are not the same.

Comment: the problem is with xml publisher report on oracle apps, the concurrent program parameters, is making some problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much!

The problem is with xml publisher / ebs concurrent parameters, just did the following and solved.

1. used the canonical_to_date in query

   Where  trunc(xx.ordered_date) between NVL(trunc(fnd_date.canonical_to_date(:P_FROM_DATE)), xx.ORDERED_DATE) and NVL(trunc(fnd_date.canonical_to_date(:P_TO_DATE)), xx.ORDERED_DATE)
2. used the FND_STANDARD_DATE value set